# Using material design component not yet built into Angular 2

Tags: css, angular, material-design

I'm looking to use some material design components such as `<md-autocomplete>`. However, this particular tag along with several others are not yet available through the [official Angular 2 material design NPM](https://github.com/angular/material2)

Is there any way to use them by specifying them as a normal class:

```
<div class="md-autocomplete">Content</div>
```

until the component is available in Angular2? If so should I include the material design CSS script in my index.html file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding it as a calss will not help you much. You can always create your own component and assign any selector you want but you will still have to do all functionality yourself. Other option is to use some existing one, like [ng2-auto-complete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-auto-complete)